# Estimating the Hausdorff distance of parallel facets of convex polytopes

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes

##### Background

Let $\mathcal{K}_P^n$ denote the class of open, convex, $n$-dimensional polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the origin. For each $K\in \mathcal{K}_P^n$, its gauge function $f_*:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,\infty)$ takes the form
$$f_*(x) = \max_{i=1,...,N} \frac{1}{d_i}\langle x,\nu_i \rangle.$$
where $\{\nu_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are the outer unit normals to $K$ and $d_i$ denotes the distance from the origin of the supporting hyperplane to $K$ with normal $\nu_i$.

Given ${\bf a}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ with $|{\bf a}|<1$ we can perturb $f_*$ by considering
$$f_*^{\bf a}(x) = \max_{i=1,...,N} \frac{1}{(1+a_i)d_i}\langle x,\nu_i\rangle.$$
This yields some $K^{\bf a}\in \mathcal{K}_P^n$, which notably has the same set of outer unit normals as $K$. We call such polytopes *parallel* to $K$.

##### The Problem

I am interested in the following: Let $K, K^{\bf a}\in \mathcal{K}_P^n$ as above. Index the facets of $K$ and $K^{\bf a}$ according to their unit normal -- that is, facet $F_i$ of $K$ has unit normal $\nu_i$. Does there exist a $C(n)>0$ such that
$$d_H(F_i,F_i^{\bf a}) \leq C(n)d_H(K,K^{\bf a}),$$
for all $i=1,...,N$? Here $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance (in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

##### My attempts

- The necessity on a dimensional constant seems evident by considering the following example: Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a rectangle with vertices $(0,0), (2,0), (2,1), (0,1)$. Considering $K^{\bf a}$ with vertices $(0,0), (0,2), (1,2), (1,0)$, if $\nu_i = e_2$ then $d_H(F_i,F_i^{\bf a})=\sqrt{2}$ while $d_H(K,K^{\bf a})=1$.
- By appealing to the realization of $K$, $K^{\bf a}$ as the convex hull of their vertices, we can show that $d_H(K,K^{\bf a}) \leq d_H(V, V^{\bf a})$, where $V$ is the set of vertices of $K$. I believe the reverse inequality to be true (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947366/hausdorff-distance-between-convex-polygons), though I'm not sure I believe the final paragraph). In any case, this doesn't really seem to help. The Hausdorff distance does not behave well under the addition/deletion of points.
- A compactness argument doesn't seem to lead anywhere. First we should make sure the $K^{\bf a}$ are uniformly bounded. Since $d_i=f(\nu_i)$, where $f$ is the surface tension of $K$, we have $f^{\bf a}(\nu_i) - f(\nu_i) = a_i f(\nu_i)$. As $d_H(K,K^{\bf a}) = \max_{\nu \in S^{n-1}} |f(\nu)-f^{\bf a}(\nu)|$ it follows that $d_H(K,K^{\bf a}) \leq M_f |{\bf a}|$, where $M_f = \max_{\nu \in S^{n-1}} f(\nu)$. Since $K\subset B_{M_f}(0)$ we have $K^{\bf a} \subset B_{M_f(1+|{\bf a}|)}(0) \subset B_{2M_f}(0)$ as $|{\bf a}|<1$. Now, supposing the statement doesn't hold there exists $K^{{\bf a}_j}$ such that $|{\bf a}_j|\to 0$ and
  $$d_H(F_i, F_i^{{\bf a}_j}) \geq j\, d_H(K,K^{{\bf a}_j}).$$
  Passing to a subsequence is probably necessary to assume the inequality fails for a specific collection of parallel facets $\{F_i^{{\bf a}_j}\}$. But this just tells us that $d_H(K,K^{{\bf a}_j})\to 0$, which we already know...
- It seems to me that only the adjacent facets to $F_i$ and $F_i^{\bf a}$ should matter, but I'm not sure what to do with this information.
- I haven't thought much about it, but maybe there's a way to prove this for strongly isomorphic polytopes and then approximate? This way there's a natural isomorphism between the vertex sets; if corresponding vertices are close enough then maybe the issues of adding/deleting points to compute the Hausdorff distance can be avoided.
- If necessary, it can be assumed that $|K^{\bf a}|=|K|$ and that $d_H(K,K^{\bf a})$ is small.

##### How to help

I'm not particularly looking for a complete proof, more so just some guidance. All the professors I know have given me their input, and they're all just as stumped as me. With that said, things that would help are

- A counterexample.
- A reference where such a result (or one close enough that I can adapt the argument) is proven.
- Other methods I could use to try and prove this. I'd rather not have a full proof unless it's clear that this problem is far more difficult than I understand it to be.

If this is the wrong place to ask such a question, then I apologize -- please refer me to the correct spot! And if anything is unclear, do let me know as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a convex polygon on the plane with one angle very close to $180^\circ$ and cut that angle by 2 different parallel lines.

Comment: This need not result in parallel polygons (as defined in the question), though. Unless I'm misunderstanding the construction.

Comment: Why? I assume that $0$ is deep inside both polygons, of course, so a small shift of one side in or out can be described as the change of the corresponding $d_i$. Am I misinterpreting the definition?